# One site has "Error Too many redirects" The other doesn't

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

I have a problem that is driving me insane.

I have an original website http://yesterdayszoo.com that works flawlessly. In particular if you scroll down and click the "try it free" button and enter the code (big) it will take you to the next page.

I have just installed exactly the same site on a different server with a different domain name (http://animalooza.com). EVERYTHING works fine except for this tiny bit. When you type in the code and click "solve" it simply displays the message "this page has a redirect loop", and I have no idea why.

I know this is an extremely vague explanation and even just a starting point would be seriously helpful in trying to figure out why one is doing one thing and the other is working fine.

Thanks in advance,

Jamie

Comment: Bad script (redirect to redirect) or bad htaccess configuration.

Comment: The second one is sending a 301 redirect (moved permanently).  Check your .htaccess (as userNOID suggests).  It may be worth regenerating your permalinks (I've seen weird HTTP response codes after moving servers, though not a 301).  And when testing, it might be worth using private/incognito mode, as your browser may cache the 301 and continue to redirect (301 is permanent, after all) - so even if you've fixed the problem you may still see it.